# Why doesn't IntelliSense lint my code on edit?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

#### Preface

I'm using Visual Studio Code for C++. (I'm choosing it over Visual Studio because It's for small homework assignments, and the overhead of Visual Studio is just not worth it.)

I'm curious to know why IntelliSense is not linting my code while I type, like it does with Python or Java. I've experimented with the Clangd extension, and it lints my code exactly as I expect, but it's incompatible with IntelliSense, so I need to disable that, but then I'm missing out on some neat IntelliSense features.

#### The question:

How can I configure IntelliSense to lint my code as I type?

c_cpp_properties.json:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

settings.json:

```json
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
  "python.linting.enabled": false,
  "cmake.configureSettings": {},
  "[cpp]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-vscode.cpptools"
  },
  "C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.beforeOpenBrace.type": "sameLine",
  "C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.beforeOpenBrace.namespace": "sameLine",
  "C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.beforeOpenBrace.lambda": "sameLine",
  "C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.beforeOpenBrace.function": "sameLine",
  "C_Cpp.vcFormat.newLine.beforeOpenBrace.block": "sameLine",
  "C_Cpp.vcFormat.wrap.preserveBlocks": "never",
  "C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "Google",
  "C_Cpp.inlayHints.autoDeclarationTypes.enabled": true,
  "C_Cpp.inlayHints.parameterNames.enabled": true,
  "C_Cpp.inlayHints.referenceOperator.enabled": true,
}
```

Comment: Why not disable IntelliSense instead and use the Clangd extension?

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, but I'd rather use IntelliSense.

Comment: I see. I wouldn't have thought anyone would prefer that with all the false errors/squiggly lines it litters the screen with.

Comment: show your c_cpp_properties.json and settings.json for a [mre].

Comment: *"I'd rather use IntelliSense"* Why?

Comment: I find that it is more helpful than clangd. Regardless of why I'd want to use it, I am still curious as to why it's not working as expected here.

Comment: FWIW, I never rely on IntelliSense because most of the time, it doesn't work.